# Deterministic Monitor Pulse/ Wait and implementing timeout in producer-consumer collection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a concurrent producer-consumer collection (multiple producers and consumers) that supports timeouts for consumers.

Now the actual collection is pretty complicated (nothing in System.Collections.Concurrent that does the job unfortunately), but I have a minimal sample here that demonstrates my problem (looks a bit like `BlockingCollection<T>`).

```
public sealed class ProducerConsumerQueueDraft<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(item);

            /* This "optimization" is broken, as Nicholas Butler points out.
            if(queue.Count == 1) // Optimization
            */
                Monitor.Pulse(locker); // Notify any waiting consumer threads.
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue(T item)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            // Surprisingly, this needs to be a *while* and not an *if*
            // which is the core of my problem.
            while (queue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(locker);

            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    // This isn't thread-safe, but is how I want TryDequeue to look.
    public bool TryDequeueDesired(out T item, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (queue.Count == 0 && !Monitor.Wait(locker, timeout))
            {
                item = default(T);
                return false;
            }

            // This is wrong! The queue may be empty even though we were pulsed!
            item = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Has nasty timing-gymnastics I want to avoid.
    public bool TryDequeueThatWorks(out T item, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (queue.Count == 0)
            {
                var remaining = timeout - watch.Elapsed;

                if (!Monitor.Wait(locker, remaining < TimeSpan.Zero ? TimeSpan.Zero : remaining))
                {
                    item = default(T);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            item = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is straightforward: consumers who find an empty queue wait to be signaled, and producers `Pulse` (note: not `PulseAll`, which would be inefficient) them to notify them of a waiting item.

My problem is this property of  [`Monitor.Pulse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse):

> When the thread that invoked Pulse releases the lock, the next
>   thread in the ready queue **(which is not necessarily the thread that
>   was pulsed)** acquires the lock.

What this means is that consumer-thread C1 could be woken up by a producer-thread to consume an item, but *another* consumer-thread C2 could acquire the lock before C1 has a chance to reacquire it, and consume the item, leaving C1 with an empty queue when it is given control.

This means I have to defensively check in the consumer code on every pulse if the queue is indeed non-empty, and go back and wait empty-handed if this not the case.

My primary issue with this is that it inefficient - threads may be woken up to do work and then promptly sent back to wait again. A related consequence of this is that implementing a `TryDequeue` with a timeout is unnecessarily difficult and inefficient (see `TryDequeueThatWorks`) when it should be elegant (see `TryDequeueDesired`).

**How can I twist `Monitor.Pulse` to do what I want? Alternatively, is there another synchronization primitive that does? Is there a more efficient and/or elegant way to implement a `TryDequeue` timeout than what I have done?**

FYI, here's a test that demonstrates the issues with my desired solution:

```
var queue = new ProducerConsumerQueueDraft<int>();

for (int consumer = 0; consumer < 3; consumer++)
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int item;

            // This call should occasionally throw an exception.
            // Switching to queue.TryDequeueThatWorks should make
            // the problem go away.
            if (queue.TryDequeueDesired(out item, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }

    }).Start();

Thread.Sleep(1000); // Let consumers get up and running

for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 50000000; itemIndex++)
{
    queue.Enqueue(0);
}
```

Comment: [BlockingCollection<T>.TryTake Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287247.aspx)?

Comment: @dtb: I know of the method. What's your point? You want me to look at the implementation? It appears to be using `SemaphoreSlim`, but I don't know how exactly it (and all of BlockingCollection) works.

Comment: From your requirements I don't understand why that method doesn't work for you.

Comment: @dtb: I'm not using `BlockingCollection`. I'm implementing a producer-consumer collection with some complex characteristics (FYI, it's a key-based conflated queue). This is just a minimal sample that demonstrates my issue - it's not my actual code.

Comment: Ah, I see. Are you sure BlockingCollection can't be twisted in some way to make it work you? For example, by combining it with a ConcurrentDictionary for the conflation part?.. Monitor.Pulse/Wait is a *very* fragile synchronization primitive; I recommend you use a different mechanism like ManualResetEventSlim, SemaphoreSlim, etc. But  it's quite difficult to give a recommendation, because I wouldn't recommend building the message queue from scratch but from existing parts.

Comment: @dtb: You caught onto what I want to do! It's true; I thought I could wrap ConcurrentDictionary and BlockingCollection to produce a conflated queue, but I abandoned it after I couldn't find an efficient way of synchronizing access to *both* of them at once. I would be happy to hear your suggestions on that (now I'm using vanilla Queue+Dictionary with locks, waits and pulses), but in the interim, I'm curious to find a solution to the problem I presented here.

Comment: This may be a good time to learn how `SemaphoreSlim` works. Its `Wait` method can accept also timespan

Comment: @L.B.: How would I use `SemaphoreSlim` here? I know `BlockingCollection` uses it, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: @Ani [Here](http://pastebin.com/v8RDZAX7) is simple BlockingQueue implementation which utilizes SemaphoreSlim. FYI: I use it in a lot of projects. so tested,

Comment: @L.B: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ani `doesn't work for me` What doesn't work for you?. Is it buggy or you want something different?

Comment: @Ani then try this http://shortText.com/rQotKWl

Comment: @L.B: Where's the TryTake with a timeout in that sample?

Comment: @Ani, There is not. But I don't think it would be hard to change the  `_ItemsInQueue.Wait();` statement in `Take` according to your requirements

Comment: @Ani It could be something like this http://shorttext.com/GK3rtEQ But I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My primary issue with this is that it inefficient

It is not.  You assume that this is a common occurrence but this kind of race happens *very* rarely.  Once in a Blue Moon, at best.  The while loop is necessary to ensure nothing goes wrong when it *does* occur.  And it will.  Don't mess with it.

It is in fact the opposite, the lock design is *efficient* because it does allow a race to occur.  And deals with it.  Tinkering with locking designs is so very dangerous because the races don't happen frequently enough.  They are horribly random which prevents sufficient testing to *prove* that the alterations don't cause failure.  Adding any instrumenting code doesn't work either, it alters the timing.

Comment: +1 Ok fair enough, maybe I'm obsessing over nothing. But is there really no primitive I could use that wouldn't cause this race? And how do I avoid the nonsense I have written in `TryDequeueThatWorks`?

Comment: Post updated.  Do consider BlockingCollection.TryTake(), it takes a timeout argument.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article about this that may help:

[Thread synchronization: Wait and Pulse demystified](http://simplygenius.net/Article/WaitPulse)

In particular, it explains why a `while` loop is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this help me? I am aware of the cause (correct me if my explanation was incorrect); I'm asking for a solution.

Comment: I suggest you read the article thoroughly and fully understand the pattern. For instance, your "optimization" in `Enqueue` is broken.

Comment: Great, now that's a statement I didn't expect! How so?

Comment: If you have an empty queue and 2 threads waiting in `Dequeue`, then if 2 items are `Enqueued`, only one of the waiting threads will be pulsed. You will be left with an item in the queue and a thread waiting in `Dequeue`.

Comment: Your article also taught me the right terminology in question. :) Anyway, as a clear expert in this area, do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: The reason I made that mistake was that I got into the trap of assuming one producer, multiple consumers (which is my actual scenario, but which I don't want to assume).

Comment: Ok. As Hans said, I don't think you have a problem with your implementation of `TryDequeueThatWorks`. You have to do a similar thing in native code when calling an alertable wait with a timeout. You have used the `while` pattern, which is necessary to ensure correctness and have added timeout support. At this level, your code is as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple key-based conflating producer-consumer queue:

```
public class ConflatingConcurrentQueue<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Entry> entries;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Entry> queue;

    public ConflatingConcurrentQueue()
    {
        this.entries = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Entry>();
        this.queue = new BlockingCollection<Entry>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(TValue value, Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        // Get the entry for the key. Create a new one if necessary.
        Entry entry = entries.GetOrAdd(keySelector(value), k => new Entry());

        // Get exclusive access to the entry.
        lock (entry)
        {
            // Replace any old value with the new one.
            entry.Value = value;

            // Add the entry to the queue if it's not enqueued yet.
            if (!entry.Enqueued)
            {
                entry.Enqueued = true;
                queue.Add(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TryDequeue(out TValue value, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Entry entry;

        // Try to dequeue an entry (with timeout).
        if (!queue.TryTake(out entry, timeout))
        {
            value = default(TValue);
            return false;
        }

        // Get exclusive access to the entry.
        lock (entry)
        {
            // Return the value.
            value = entry.Value;

            // Mark the entry as dequeued.
            entry.Enqueued = false;
            entry.Value = default(TValue);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class Entry
    {
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
        public bool Enqueued { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*(This may need a code review or two, but I think in general it's sane.)*

Comment: (Struggling thinking of all the possible interleavings) :)

Comment: I'm pretty confident that it works in all possible interleavings. However, there is one problem with the code: the Entry objects are never removed from the dictionary. I haven't managed yet to come up with a solution that does this and works in all possible interleavings.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is correct (not saying it's wrong, but it's difficult to think about) , but it is certainly very clever and deserves a +1.